# Creating a Selector in redux not working

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to create a selector of this :

```
const getProducts = (state, { productId }) => {
  let quantity = 0;
  if (state.cart[productId].quantity) {
    quantity = state.cart[productId].quantity;
  }

  return {
    accumulatedPrice:
      state.cart[productId].quantity * state.products[productId].price,
    id: productId,
    image: state.products[productId].image,
    price: state.products[productId].price,
    quantity: quantity
  };
};
```

I'm trying to do so with :

```
const getLineItem = createSelector([getProducts], products =>
  Object.values(products)
);
```

But I'm getting [] instead of {}

What I'm missing?

Comment: What **exactly** is the expected line output of `getLineItem`?

Comment: the same of getProducts(), but I want it to be the same instance, so I need to do it with selector, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very rough example would be this:

```
const getProducts = (state) => state.products;
const getCart = (state) => state.cart;
const getProductId = (state, props) => props.productId;


const getLineItem = createSelector(
    [getProducts, getCart, getProductId],
    (products, cart, productId) => ({
        accumulatedPrice: cart[productId].quantity * products[productId].price,
        id: productId,
        image: products[productId].image,
        price: products[productId].price,
        quantity: cart[productId].quantity || 0
    })
)
```

You could also refine this further if you wanted and have `getCartProduct` (combined with `getProductId`) as well as `getProduct` (again combined with `getProductId`), but this should serve as a starting block.

Comment: I need to know how to get the state and productId from getLineItem method

Comment: Plus I need to do this logic  let quantity = 0;
  if (state.cart[productId].quantity) {
    quantity = state.cart[productId].quantity;
  } otherwise quantity will give to me undefined

Comment: @StuartDTO Can you explain further? You can access any part of the `state` by creating a selector for that part of the state eg. `const getProducts = state => state.products` and then pass that as argument to your selector.

Comment: @StuartDTO `cart[productId].quantity || 0` does what you described here. If quantity is `undefined` it will return `0`

Comment: @StuartDTO That means `cart[productId]` does not exist (ie. is `undefined`), meaning there is no such product in the cart. Are you sure that should be allowed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172970/discussion-between-stuartdto-and-s).